# Tensorflow : Value Error , cannot feed value of (64,) to (?, 27)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tflearn

I am new python and right now i have this problem.
I am trying to make a CNN model for 27 classifications . But i am getting this error 
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64,) for Tensor 'targets/Y:0', which has shape '(?, 27)'[here is the picture of my error[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q739.png)

here is my code I ll really appreciate any suggestions and comments 
P.S i am new to this so , apologies in advance for noob mistake

```
import numpy as np, cv2, os
import tflearn
import parser
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression

img_size = 50

LR = 1e-3
MODEL_N = 'wood-{}-{}.model'.format(LR, '2conv-basic')


folders = ['alan batu', 'alan bunga', 'bindang', 'bintangor',
'dark red meranti',
'durian','geronggang','jelutong','jongkong','kapur','keruing',
'light red meranti',
'menggris','merbau','mersawa','nyatoh','perupok','pulai','ramin',
'rengas','resak','selangan batu','sepetir','terentang',
'white meranti','yellow meranti']
 labels = []
 images = []
for folder in folders:
for path in os.listdir('C:/Users/mwasi/Desktop/AI/pictures/sorted/'+folder):
    img = 
  cv2.imread('C:/Users/mwasi/Desktop/AI/pictures/sorted/'+folder+'/'+path,0)

    images.append(cv2.resize(img, (img_size, img_size)))
    labels.append(folders.index(folder))


  to_train= 0
   training_data =[]
 testing_data =[]

 train_images, test_images, train_labels, test_labels = [],[],[],[]
for image, label in zip(images, labels):
   if to_train<5:
    train_images.append(image)
    train_labels.append(label)
    to_train+=1
    training_data.append ([np.array(image), np.array(label)])
else:
    test_images.append(image)
    test_labels.append(label)
    to_train = 0
    testing_data.append ([np.array(image), np.array(label)])

 print('# of training images: ', len(train_images))
 print('# of testimg images: ', len(test_images))
np.save('train_data.npy',training_data)
np.save('testing_data.npy',testing_data)


convnet = input_data(shape=[None, img_size,img_size, 1], name='input')

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5,padding='valid', activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation='relu')
convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.4)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet,27, activation='softmax')
convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, 
loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')

model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir='log')

train_data = np.load('train_data.npy')
test_data=np.load('train_data.npy')

if os.path.exists('{}.meta'.format(MODEL_N)):
  model.load(MODEL_NAME)
  print('model loaded')

train = train_data[:-50]
test = train_data[-50:]

X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,img_size,img_size,1)
Y = [i[1] for i in train]

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1, img_size, img_size, 1)
test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=3, validation_set=({'input': 
test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), 
snapshot_step=10, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_N)
```

Comment: what is the library that you are using on tensorflow? Functions dont look like neither keras, pytorch or tensorflow. If not post you conv_2d, max_pool_2d and fully_connected functions.

Answer (score 0):

It means that your tensor's shapes don't fit the shapes you desired. In your case, you were trying to feed shape of 64 to 27. I think this line of code `convnet = fully_connected(convnet,27, activation='softmax')` that made this error happened, you have to change the shape of the previous layer first.

Comment: By my understanding 'convnet = fully_connected(convnet,27, activation='softmax')' is where i declared the classification and the previous layers are reading features out of the images.

Comment: I tried changing the previous layers but still getting this error

Answer (score 0):

How many rows does Y have: 64? Y should have 27 columns! What is the shape of train_data and how is it structured?
Note: I would have liked to make a comment, but I can only answer to this post.

Answer (score 0):

The input you have mentioned for y label is ***targets*** which will be used for calculating error, so it should have been a 27-dimensional array, same as the output for convnet output, but since the input is defined as  :

```
convnet = input_data(shape=[None, img_size,img_size, 1], name='input')
```

means the input tensor can have arbitrary batch size (i.e. the number of images that are feeded to the model will be decided during runtime.) and each image in a batch will have size **img_size x img_size x 1**. Hence label targets will also have a shape (batch_size, 27)

Now the model is created, and during runtime you feed the model using :

```
X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,img_size,img_size,1)
Y = [i[1] for i in train]
```

Where X does have a shape **[len(train) ,img_size,img_size,1 ]** but y has a shape **(len(train)*len(i[1]),)**. but it should be  **(len(train),27)**

so what you want to do is

```
Y = [[i[1]] for i in train]  # Y shape will be now (len(train), shape(i[1]))
```

where i[1] is supposed to be a 27-dimensional array.

Remember your error means placeholder and input size mismatch. You have to account for the batch size